# Google BigTable to BigQuery sync using Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to sync data (incremental) from Google BigTable to BigQuery using Google Dataflow? In my scenario, I have stream of data flowing into Google BigTable since it has low latency read/writes. Then planning to have some kind of pipeline to make BigQuery table eventually consistent.

Also, if we are using Dataflow to sync data from BigTable, then we need to design rowkey, so that we could avoid complex table scan. Is that right?

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: Yes, you can use Dataflow to process data in BigTable to BigQuery. Dataflow has a Java connector for BigTable, but no Python connector. Do you plan to stream or batch updates? Your question does not have enough information to recommend options, just that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks John for the response! I am thinking of streaming option for updates. Any idea how that could be done in GCP?

Comment: Edit your question with a lot more details on what your secenario is, types of data, volume of data, how often data needs to sync, data source, etc.